# Get class name Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse some html for android app, but I can't get the value for the *data-id* class

Here's the html code

```
 <div class="popup event-popup Predavanja" style="display: none;" data-id="246274" data-position="bottom" >
```

How can I parse the **246274** value?

Comment: what and how you tried to solve? Kindly paste your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `Element` object of the `div` tag, then this code will work:

```
String attr = element.attr("data-id"); // get the value of the 'data-id' attribute
int dataID = Integer.parseInt(attr); // convert it to an int
```

Optionally, if you want to check first if the attribute even exists, use this:

```
if (element.hasAttr("data-id")) // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this

```
Document doc  = JSoup.parse(""Url");
Element  divElement = doc.select("div.popup event-popup Predavanja").first();//Div with class name

String dataId = divElement.attr("data-id");
```

Follow this link https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax